# Creating a fake database using a text file

Tags: java, database

I'm currently running into a bit of an issue that I cannot seem to grasp. I am creating a fake database that allows me to add, remove, and display data. But I must use a seperate text file that contains information for the data that will display the data on the java program. I'm just not sure how to import my text file so I can make changes to it from my java file. Here is some of my code to get a better picture:

This is the class I will be inputting information for my text file and ultimately creating a database.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class Database {

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("employees.txt");

    //Vector <Employee> employees = new Vector <Employee>();

}
```

And here is my text file I will be using:

```
Blue Potato, Current Employee

Asheley Yeh, Former Employee
```

This is the information I want to print within in my java file from my text file, and then have the capability to edit my information from the java file and he changes will ultimately appear in my text file.

Comment: You might want to consider using an *embedded database*, such as Apache Derby.

Comment: In-Memory database h2 may be a good option here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't write the class "Database" directly in the file ?

Using this : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

You have just to make Employee Serializable and then write it to the file

And to reload the fake database :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-object-from-file-in-java/

Comment: I recieved some advice to write a Vector that can go through the text list. Is that another option?

Comment: With your solution, if i clearly understood, you store each line as an entry in a Vector object. But if you write the object directly, you just retrieve it as the same Type. If you save the object Database, you can retrieve directly an object of type Database by providing your textfile url. It's usefull if you have complexe object graph for example.

Comment: In your case you just have employee object with primitive type in (i supposed). But if in the futur you have an object "Company", "Adress" in the class "Employee", it's easier to store the top level object (here Database).

Comment: That sounds about right but, and I apologize for this, could you show me a random written example of this? I do want to print each line using a vector which I have put in my code above but commented out. The issue I ran into with it was that it couldn't find my textfile. Could you possibly show me a way to input the file name so I can correctly implement my database from my text file?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't speak eglish very well, you want an exemple to write the Database object into your text file ?

Comment: Yes, please. I just want to make sure I understand exactly what you mean, because it sounds like were on the same page.

Comment: i didn't test the code, but i think it works, don't forget to enclose all in a try catch block : http://sharetext.org/fgt1

Comment: Alright, I believe this will solve my problem. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: No problem :-), Don't hesitate to ask me if you have other problems, the code i posted on sharetext is very light and not complete ;-)